# heat sink solution for light source around 1000°C

Tags: circuit-design, temperature, heatsink

I'm going to use a infrared light source [IR12k](http://hawkeyetechnologies.com/source-selection/ir1x/) which can reach 975°C for my design. However, I'm not sure whether I can solder this light source with cable whose other end is soldered with power board. This is because the temperature of the light source is obviously above the melting point of the solder tin. My concern is that the solder joint may get loose or melted when the source light is working. If so, is there any safe heat sinking solution that can avoid the melt of solder tin in this situation?

Comment: Did you find a proper datasheet for the product (rather than a catalogue page)? I'd say it's supposed to be soldered to a board with very large pad area to take away the heat and that there will be a large temperature gradient along the pins so that the soldered joints will be at a much, much lower temperature. The datasheet should give a suggested layout for use.

Comment: Looks as though it is intended to be used in a lamp socket -G5 or GU5 seems possible - which would isolate the heat.

Answer (score 2):

They claim it can be mounted on a PCB. Easy enough to test it on a bit of perf board, though the manufacturer should be able to advise. Definitely put the reflector shield in place.

I suggest using a couple of Mill-Max socket pins.

It's only 11W, so aside from IR radiation heating the PCB, it's not necessarily much worse than an 11W power transistor.

Note: If/when you get a definitive answer from the manufacturer or supplier, you should make your own answer and choose it.

Answer (score 2):

> The **coiled filament** operates at 900°C when powered with 10 watts

Only the filament gets hot. Which is wound around a ceramic rod suspensed on two steel poles. Before this 10 Watt conducts down to the solder joints of your connector it needs to heat the metal and ceramic base which you can inserted in a heatsink.

I suspect you can't solder the steel pins, so a solder joint failure is impossible.

*Also it's 80 GBP, you can ask the vendor for that.*